# Is a graph 1 particle irreducible if the split would change the number of external legs?

Tags: feynman-diagrams

Is a graph 1 particle irreducible if the split would change the number of external legs? For example;
http://www.stevepur.com/physics/matter/matter40.gif
(sorry, image upload is giving errors)

The graph could be split by cutting one propagator, but the resulting graph would have a different number of external legs. Is it 1PR or not?